# JBoss 7 domain mode custom log location configuration

Tags: logging, configuration, customization, jboss7.x

We have JBoss 7.1.1 in Domain Mode.
I have been trying to configure a different location for

- server.log (for each master/slave server) 
  boot.log (for each master/slave server) 
  host-controller.log. 
  process-controller.log.

What files & parameters do we need to edit to get the log locations customized?
Any help in figuring this out is monumentally appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

There already should be a separate boot.log and server.log for each server. The host-controller.log and the process-controller.log are all configured with the same logging configuration file. I don't think they can be separated, but I'm not a domain mode expert.

Comment: got it but how and where do i configure that please?

Comment: You have to override the `jboss.server.log.dir` system property for the server.log. IIRC it might not work for the boot.log. In WildFly and EAP 6.1 the boot.log has been removed.

Comment: what about  host-controller.log. process-controller.log  please?

Comment: IIRC there were some bugs getting those two logs to the correct directory. You can try setting the `jboss.domain.log.dir`. I'm pretty sure as of EAP 6.1 that works. It might be EAP 6.0 too, but I honestly can't remember. The script could be fixed for it to work though regardless.

Answer (score 0):

You could add paths tag before management tag in standalone.xml or in domain.xml

```
<paths>
    <path name="custom.jboss.server.log.dir" path="/opt/nfs/logs/jboss/"/>
</paths>
```

After you to declare this tags you could change logs dir in jboss log4j subsystem.

You change jboss.server.log.dir by custom.jboss.server.log.dir

```
            <periodic-rotating-file-handler name="FILE" autoflush="true">
                <level name="DEBUG"/>
                <formatter>
                    <pattern-formatter pattern="%d{HH:mm:ss} %-5p [%c] (%t) %s%E%n"/>
                </formatter>
                <file relative-to="jboss.server.log.dir" path="server.log"/>
                <suffix value=".yyyy-MM-dd"/>
                <append value="true"/>
            </periodic-rotating-file-handler>
```